# Error running SQL via Hibernate's createSQLQuery()

Tags: sql, hibernate

using hibernate 3.2.1 (can't be changed to modern version)

I want to get entity from DB by it's property 'code' without spases. I try to do it with the following query

```
    return (Good) getSession().createSQLQuery("from Good where REPLACE(code, \" \", \"\")=?").setString(0, code).uniqueResult();
```

but I have an exception.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from Good where REPLACE(code, " ", "")='AG221'' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1778)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
... 58 more
```

I'll be grateful for any advice.

Comment: createSQLQuery() expects a complete, valid SQL statement, but you only supply a fragment.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with JSF. Edited out.

Answer (score 0):

You generate an SQLQuery. you have to start with `select`

```
return (Good) getSession().createSQLQuery("select * from Good where REPLACE(code, \" \", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

createSQLQuery will return SQLQuery for execution of native SQL queries. see ["Using a SQLQuery"](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-creating). so
please try with **createQuery** for HQL.

```java
return (Good) getSession().createQuery("from Good where REPLACE(code, \" \", \"\")=?").setString(0, code).uniqueResult();
```